# Temporary extra space on top of UICollectionView w/ navigation bar

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar

There are a couple of things wrong with my UICollectionView and corresponding cells that are under a navigation bar. First of all, when the view first loads, there seems to be some extra space on the top. But when I do a little scroll down (not a full scroll), it adjusts to normal height. Check out the images below for what I mean. [this is what I see when i first open the view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbEbm.png)

[after a little scroll, not a full one (There are 10 cells in this VC), i see this. Why is this happening?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bOhr.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your viewcontroller uncheck  **Adjust Scroll View Insets**

[image]

Comment: Can you try setting ContentInset for collection view ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your storyboard in your view controller select your collectionView and from the side pane select size inspector there is an option of content insets set it to Never. [image]